# ng-options get referenced document and display its field as value for dropdown population

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with meteor+angular. The following loops through all the documents in the `items` collection. Within the loop, once a `meal == true` is hit, it loops the related `combos` to make dropdowns that use as options, documents from the `comboitems` collection.

```
// controller.ng.js
angular.module("myApp").controller("menuCtrl",
    function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor){

        $scope.items = $meteor.collection(Items);
        $scope.combos = $meteor.collection(Combos);
        $scope.comboitems = $meteor.collection(Comboitems);
    }
);

// view.ng.html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-if="true === item.meal">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="combo in combos | filter: {itemId: item._id}">
                <select ng-model="comboitems" ng-options="comboitem.itemId for comboitem in (comboitems | filter: {comboId: combo._id})"></select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the data provided below, once I hit `Pizza Meal` I will have two dropdowns: `Choose your pizza` and `Choose your drink`, where in the former I will be able to choose between `pizza 1` and `pizza 2`, while in the latter between `drink 1` and `drink 2`.

This is the result

[image]

My issue is that I can't find a way to render the `item.name`, knowing its id in the `comboitems` collection once the `<select>` is being rendered.

Here is a sample data showing how the relations work:

```
items collection:

_id | name       | price | meal
---------------------------------
a   | pizza 1    | 5.00  | false
b   | pizza 2    | 6.00  | false
c   | drink 1    | 1.00  | false
d   | drink 2    | 1.00  | false
e   | Pizza meal | 5.00  | true

combos collection:

_id | name               | itemId
-----------------------------------
x   | Choose your pizza  | e
y   | Choose your drink  | e

comboitems collection:

_id | itemId | comboId
-----------------------
1   | a      | x
2   | b      | x
3   | c      | y
3   | d      | y
```

Comment: This is a bit vague.  There is no `title` field in your data as your question suggests, and what do you mean by you want to "return" it?  Perhaps you could show  an example of what your expected output is, or, even better, provide a plunker demo?

Comment: You're right, I've corrected the question with the right field name and tried to explain better

Comment: Still not sure what your actual question is.  Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a playground that allows to set up meteor-angular as I am using it. I've updated the question with a better explanation and with an image to show how the  code is being rendered.

Comment: This problem is not related to meteor, its solely a binding issue in angularjs.  You should attempt to remove the dependency on meteor and provide a demo.  Doing so will result in your question being answered much quicker (if at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `select` **`as`** in your `ng-options` directive:

```
<select ng-model="selectesdItem" 
    ng-options="comboitem.itemId as getName(comboitem.itemId) for comboitem in (comboitems | filter: {comboId: combo._id})">
</select>
```

and bind the result to a function that will return the name:

```
$scope.getName = function(id) {
    return $filter('filter')($scope.items, { _id: id }, true)[0].name;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/efym7LpeSjIqkDKbdLR0?p=preview

Comment: Great, thank you. I'm new to both Angular and Meteor and therefore I'm still having issue understanding how it all ties together.

Comment: One issue, though. Why is that when I click an option in the dropdown this gets emptied? You can see in your very pinkr

Comment: @cellulosa that was because of a naming collision, using `comboitems` as `ng-model`.  I've updated it.